# Kernels of the surjection from trivial vector bundle to $\mathcal{O}(k)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Is there a way to understand the Harder-Narasimhan filtration (the slopes appearing) for the kernel bundle of the surjection $\mathcal{O}^n \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(k)\rightarrow 0$ on an algebraic curve? Here $n=dim(\Gamma(\mathcal{O}(k)))$.